# Convert columns into multiple rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that looks something like this:

```
   Deal  Year  Quarter_1  Quarter_2  Quarter_3  Financial_Data
h     1  1991          1          2          3             120
i     2  1992          4          5          6              80
j     3  1993          7          8          9             100
```

I want to combine all the quarters into one new column and copy the deal number, year and financial data. The end result should then look like this:

```
   Deal  Year  Quarter  Financial_Data
h     1  1991        1             120
i     1  1991        2             120
j     1  1991        3             120
k     2  1992        4              80
l     2  1992        5              80
m     2  1992        6              80
n     3  1993        7             100
o     3  1993        8             100
p     3  1993        9             100
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how is it not working as expected ?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything, i'm new to python and don't how i would even approach this problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `melt` method.

```
df = pd.melt(d, id_vars=["Deal", "Year", "Financial_Data"], 
             value_name="Quarter").drop(['variable'],axis=1).sort_values('Quarter')
```

Output

```
   Deal  Year  Financial_Data  Quarter
0     1  1991             120        1
3     1  1991             120        2
6     1  1991             120        3
1     2  1992              80        4
4     2  1992              80        5
7     2  1992              80        6
2     3  1993             100        7
5     3  1993             100        8
8     3  1993             100        9
```

If you have many columns, you can use `df.columns.tolist()` method in order to achieve your requirement.

```
column_list = df.columns.tolist()
id_vars_list = column_list[:2] + column_list[-1:]
```

The statement will become

```
df = pd.melt(d, id_vars=id_vars_list, 
             value_name="Quarter").drop(['variable'],axis=1).sort_values('Quarter')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One more question, I have a rather large dataset with over 200 columns is there any shortcut so i dont have to enter all the headings into id_vars?

Comment: @Dan, my thought was to get first two columns and the last one.

Answer (score 3):

This is done using `melt`:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Deal','Year','Financial_Data'], value_vars=['Quarter_1','Quarter_2','Quarter_3'])
   Deal  Year  Financial_Data   variable  value
0     1  1991             120  Quarter_1      1
1     2  1992              80  Quarter_1      4
2     3  1993             100  Quarter_1      7
3     1  1991             120  Quarter_2      2
4     2  1992              80  Quarter_2      5
5     3  1993             100  Quarter_2      8
6     1  1991             120  Quarter_3      3
7     2  1992              80  Quarter_3      6
8     3  1993             100  Quarter_3      9
```

Cleaning it up a little:

```
>>> pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Deal','Year','Financial_Data'], value_vars=['Quarter_1','Quarter_2','Quarter_3']).drop('variable',axis=1).sort_values('value')
   Deal  Year  Financial_Data  value
0     1  1991             120      1
3     1  1991             120      2
6     1  1991             120      3
1     2  1992              80      4
4     2  1992              80      5
7     2  1992              80      6
2     3  1993             100      7
5     3  1993             100      8
8     3  1993             100      9
```

Comment: Yes, just extract a list of the columns you want from `df.columns`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to combine your Quarter_X data into a list. Then expand the list series via `numpy` / `itertools` in a new dataframe.

This is usually more efficient than `stack` or `groupby` based methods. Note that the resulting index is extracted from the parent row. You will need to reindex as required.

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np

df['Quarters'] = list(zip(df.Quarter_1, df.Quarter_2, df.Quarter_3))

lens = list(map(len, df.Quarters))

res = pd.DataFrame({'Deal': np.repeat(df.Deal, lens),
                    'Year': np.repeat(df.Year, lens),
                    'Quarter': list(chain.from_iterable(df.Quarters)),
                    'FinancialData': np.repeat(df.FinancialData, lens)})

print(res)

   Deal  FinancialData  Quarter  Year
h     1            120        1  1991
h     1            120        2  1991
h     1            120        3  1991
i     2             80        4  1992
i     2             80        5  1992
i     2             80        6  1992
j     3            100        7  1993
j     3            100        8  1993
j     3            100        9  1993
```

---

For multiple columns, the above method *may* be expensive, but you could do:

```
res = pd.DataFrame({**{'Quarter': list(chain.from_iterable(df.Quarters))},
                    **{k: np.repeat(df[k], lens) for k in df if 'Quarter' not in k}})
```

Comment: I have to do this for a rather large dataset, around 200 different columns, is there any way that I do not have to type out 'Deal': np.repeat(df.Deal, lens) for every single heading?